# How to handle asMany relationship in Collapse::widget on Yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, widget, has-many

I'm working in a small tickets module on my system made in yii2, these tickets are composed of notes, which I want to be in the summary of each ticket, I want to use the Collapse widget yii2 (http: // www .yiiframework.com / doc-2.0 / yii-bootstrap-collapse.html) to display the list of associated notes but I'm finding the following error: Trying to get property of non-object

**Models**

*Ticket*

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['content','subject'], 'string'],
    ];
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_ticket' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Ticket'),
        'subject' => Yii::t('app', 'Subject'),
        'content' => Yii::t('app', 'Content'),
    ];
}

public function getNotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Nota::className(), ['ticket_id' => 'id_ticket']);
}
```

*Note*

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['content','subject'], 'string'],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_note' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Note'),
        'ticket_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Ticket ID'),
        'subject' => Yii::t('app', 'subject'),
        'content' => Yii::t('app', 'content'),
    ];
}

public function getTicket()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Ticket::className(), ['id_ticket' => 'ticket_id']);
}
```

**View**

```
Collapse::widget([
                   'items' => [
                        [
                        'label' => $model->notes->subject,
                        'content' => $model->notes->content,
                        ],
                    ]
                 ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to iterate throug the notes:

```
$notes= [];

foreach($model->notes as $note) {
  $notes[] = [
    'label' => $note->subject,
    'content' => $note->content,
  ];
}
```

and then assigne the notes to the widget:

```
Collapse::widget(['items' => $nodes]);
```

hope that helps :)